# Join a csv and topojson using d3

Tags: javascript, csv, join, d3.js, topojson

I am new in github and topojson. I am trying to join a csv and topojson to create a map in github.

```
(function(){

//Variables used based on CSV column headers
var attrArray = ["StateMedHomeVal", "AnnualTax217k", "AnnualTaxMedHomeVal"]; //list of attributes
var expressed = attrArray[0]; //initial attribute
var pie, arc, labelArc,chartTitle,colorScale;


//begin script when window loads
window.onload = setMap();
window.onload = donut(expressed);

//set up choropleth map
function setMap() {

    //map frame dimensions
    var width = 795,
        height = 450;

    //create new svg container for the map
    var map = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "map")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    //create Albers equal area conic projection centered on France
    var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
        .center([0, 43.5])
        .rotate([98, 4, 0])
        .parallels([45.00, 45.5])
        .scale(800)
        .translate([width / 2.00, height / 2.00]);

    var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);
                       

    //use Promise.all to parallelize asynchronous data loading
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(d3.csv("data/CensusRealEstateData.csv")); //load attributes from csv
    promises.push(d3.json("data/StatesLayerTopo.topojson")); //load choropleth spatial data
    Promise.all(promises).then(callback);

    function callback(data) {
        [csv, json] = data;
        //place graticule on the map
        setGraticule(map, path);
        console.log(json)
        //asigns variable to state objects
        var states = json.features;
        console.log(states)
        //join csv data to GeoJSON enumeration units
        states = joinData(states, csv);
        console.log(states)
        //create the color scale
        

    };
};//end of setMap()   

   // };
    function joinData(states, csv){
        //...DATA JOIN LOOPS FROM EXAMPLE 1.1
        //loop through csv to assign each set of csv attribute values to geojson county
        for (var i=0; i<csv.features; i++){
            var csvState = csv[i]; //the current state
            var csvKey = csvState.State; //the CSV primary key
            console.log(states.features)
            //loop through geojson counties to find correct county, change from counties to states
            for (var a=0; a< 51 ; a++){
                console.log(states.properties)
                var geojsonProps = states[a].properties; //the current county geojson properties
                var geojsonKey = geojsonProps.State; //the geojson primary key
                console.log(csvKey)
                console.log(geojsonKey)
                //where primary keys match, transfer csv data to geojson properties object
                if (geojsonKey == csvKey){

                    //assign all attributes and values
                    attrArray.forEach(function(attr){
                        var val = parseFloat(csvState[attr]); //get csv attribute value
                        geojsonProps[attr] = val; //assign attribute and value to geojson properties
                    });
                };
            };
        };
        console.log(states)
        return states;
    };
```

Here are my errors:

Uncaught (in promise) {State: 'Alabama', AnnualTax217k: '895', StateMedHomeVal: '142700', AnnualTaxMedHomeVal: '587'}

The topojson will not join with the csv file. I only get the grid of a map plane, I cannot see the states and the topojson I converted using mapstarter. How can I fix this ?